Is my Linux inside virtual box being hacked or is it my base system; windows which is compromised?
There's a Oracle Linux running inside a Virtual Box, which is running on Windows 11 home.
Need help understanding:
Is there any chance of any of either the linux or , as this clearly appears to be a brute-force dictionary attack. But, as the IPv6 one is question appears to be that of the router, could it be that the underlying system is hacked?
How to mitigate this situation.
What could be the entry point - atleast ways to go about finding one.
If there could be any backdoors, how to find them.
Right after installing Oracle Linux, I find a lot of failed attempts on the root user.
log file path:/var/log/secure
The IP in question is: fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6
Nov  9 18:26:44 OracleLinux polkitd[1038]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
Nov  9 18:26:44 OracleLinux polkitd[1038]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
Nov  9 18:26:44 OracleLinux polkitd[1038]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 5 rules
Nov  9 18:26:44 OracleLinux polkitd[1038]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
Nov  9 18:26:45 OracleLinux unix_chkpwd[1088]: password check failed for user (root)
Nov  9 18:26:45 OracleLinux sshd[1057]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8  user=root
Nov  9 18:26:46 OracleLinux unix_chkpwd[1358]: password check failed for user (root)
Nov  9 18:26:46 OracleLinux sshd[1261]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.29.1  user=root
Nov  9 18:26:47 OracleLinux sshd[1057]: Failed password for root from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45545 ssh2
Nov  9 18:27:46 OracleLinux sshd[1261]: Failed password for root from 192.168.29.1 port 43718 ssh2
Nov  9 18:27:47 OracleLinux sshd[1057]: Received disconnect from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45545:11: SSH client disconnected [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:47 OracleLinux sshd[1057]: Disconnected from authenticating user root fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45545 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:47 OracleLinux sshd[1579]: Invalid user admin from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45547
Nov  9 18:27:47 OracleLinux sshd[1579]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov  9 18:27:47 OracleLinux sshd[1579]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8
Nov  9 18:27:48 OracleLinux sshd[1261]: Received disconnect from 192.168.29.1 port 43718:11: SSH client disconnected [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:48 OracleLinux sshd[1261]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 192.168.29.1 port 43718 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:48 OracleLinux sshd[1584]: Invalid user admin from 192.168.29.1 port 43720
Nov  9 18:27:48 OracleLinux sshd[1584]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov  9 18:27:48 OracleLinux sshd[1584]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.29.1
Nov  9 18:27:50 OracleLinux sshd[1579]: Failed password for invalid user admin from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45547 ssh2
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux systemd[1590]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user devoracleuser(uid=1000) by devoracleuser(uid=0)
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux sshd[1584]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 192.168.29.1 port 43720 ssh2
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux login[836]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user devoracleuser(uid=1000) by devoracleuser(uid=0)
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux login[836]: LOGIN ON tty1 BY devoracleuser
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux sshd[1584]: Received disconnect from 192.168.29.1 port 43720:11: SSH client disconnected [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux sshd[1584]: Disconnected from invalid user admin 192.168.29.1 port 43720 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux unix_chkpwd[1630]: password check failed for user (root)
Nov  9 18:27:51 OracleLinux sshd[1628]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.29.1  user=root
Nov  9 18:27:53 OracleLinux sshd[1579]: Received disconnect from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45547:11: SSH client disconnected [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:53 OracleLinux sshd[1579]: Disconnected from invalid user admin fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45547 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:53 OracleLinux unix_chkpwd[1633]: password check failed for user (root)
Nov  9 18:27:53 OracleLinux sshd[1631]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8  user=root
Nov  9 18:27:54 OracleLinux sshd[1628]: Failed password for root from 192.168.29.1 port 43721 ssh2
Nov  9 18:27:55 OracleLinux sshd[1631]: Failed password for root from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45550 ssh2
Nov  9 18:27:56 OracleLinux sshd[1628]: Received disconnect from 192.168.29.1 port 43721:11: SSH client disconnected [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:56 OracleLinux sshd[1628]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 192.168.29.1 port 43721 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:57 OracleLinux sshd[1631]: Received disconnect from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45550:11: SSH client disconnected [preauth]
Nov  9 18:27:57 OracleLinux sshd[1631]: Disconnected from authenticating user root fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45550 [preauth]
Nov  9 18:28:57 OracleLinux sshd[1639]: Invalid user 888888 from 192.168.29.1 port 43725
Nov  9 18:28:57 OracleLinux sshd[1639]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov  9 18:28:57 OracleLinux sshd[1639]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.29.1
Nov  9 18:28:58 OracleLinux sshd[1641]: Invalid user 888888 from fe80::e20e:e4ff:fe26:d5a6%enp0s8 port 45554

Wireshark entries of the same IP, the following day:

Is there any chance that my systems are compromised?

Do you know the root password if you ever SSH in as root? Also, have you disabled root login over SSH?

ssh root@server_ip does not work - as in, it keeps for asking password after entering thee root password. But, if I go from application user to the root user, using the same password, it does work. I have not disabled root as such, but it wasn't enabled in the first place.

Check the sshd config file.  See if there is a PermitRootLogin line. Set that to no, if there is, then install sudo if you haven't already.  Can you login to the VM directly as root?

The "#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password"  is commented out. I have added a line "PermitRootLogin no". Also, no, I cannot login to the VM directly as root.

Now restart the sshd service by rebooting the VM, login as your user, the use su - to become root.  As root install sudo then use visudo to add your user to your distribution's preferred group, either the sudo group or the wheel group and be sure to require a password, i.e. don't uncomment Allow Access with no password, and use sudo every time you need to work as root.

Have configured this.

Great now clear the logs, or just check them in a few days.  The SSH root access attempts will have disappeared.  Be aware that other items, involving other attack vectors may appear.  If that happens, then we need to secure each vector as it comes, until we've closed all holes.  The root over SSH is the biggest vector that I've seen in most cases.

It's common even on headless Virtual Machines to attempt the easiest takeover method common to hackers.  Most first time SSH users forget to secure root entry into any flavor Linux via SSH. Leaving PermitRootLogin out of the config file does not imply it's set to no. The default is actually yes. It's always better to put the option in and set it.
See: sshd_config manpage - Ancient Manpage
sshd_config manpage - Newer/OpenBSD Manpage
Thanks @dave_thompson_085
Disabling root login prevents hackers from penetration testing.  This is what looks like is happening to the OP by looking at the logs. By disabling root access, we have prevented internet wide attacks. To consider securing this further, take a look at AllowUsers also on the manpage.
Check the logs over the next few days and the attacks should lessen.  If they haven't the other types of attacks will no longer be masked by a root login failure.
Extra Information
After answering, and doing some extra mulling over of  terdon's comment below, I decided to investigate:

86 Neighbor Solicitation - See Neighbor Discovery Protocol - Function Type 135
62 Router Solicitation - See again Neighbor Discovery Protocol - Function Type 134.  See also: ICMP Router Discovery Protocol. This is the IPv4 version of Neighbor Discovery.
Relevant RFC's: 4861 and 4862.

While these messages can now be deemed harmless due to discovering what they are, I feel more log investigation is warranted here as the requests are occurring at a rather high rate.  The next things I would check are:

The logs (the same ones the OP posted), after closing the SSH hole.
The IPv6 router settings. The requests could be turned down.  If they are turned down, but still occur afterwards by looking at #1 above this would indicate a Distributed Denial of Service attack.
A Mac Address Lookup Tool. Since the OP provided a WireShark screenshot, here's their version of the tool: Wireshark OUI lookup tool. To use: Paste the MAC addresses at the end of the Info column from the screenshot, Press Find.  Make sure that the resulting Manufacturer matches the network cards in computers inside the LAN.


Isn't the fact that this was coming from an internal IP worth investigating though?  192.168.29.1 is an internal IP, and the OP even said that the IPv6 IP was the IP of their router. I know very little about networking, but doesn't that suggest the attackers have at least gained entry to the local network?

Possibly, but I'm hoping that the attack vector we closed will lead to the outside source.  I argue that closing the local LAN attack  and looking at the logs will show the port that is open that the attacker(s) gained access through.  If not there, hopefully the OP's modem/router has logging facilities which will be the next place to look.  The fact that it's coming from the probable default gateway doesn't tell us much at the moment, other than the OP misconfigured something in the router or the ISP gave the OP a sub-par modem/router combo.

Actually since 7.0 in 2015 the default for PermitRootLogin is prohibit-password -- as documented in the upstream-and-common sshd_config file itself and a non-ancient version of the man page

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the newer manpage.

It's very likely not a break-in attempt from outside but the VirtualBox host trying to install its extensions into the guest VM. Take a look at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html or at your local VirtualBox documentation. It's a long time since I used VirtualBox, so I can't give more detailed help.
